# Conditionally removing a row and another one after that in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

In a large data frame I want to remove a row where there is a 1 in column 6. Additionally the row after that one should also be removed. Anyone who has an answer to that?

```
    1        1      neutral            3  450    0
    2        1          con            1  538    0
    3        1      neutral            3  609    0
    4        1          inc            0  451    0
    5        1          inc            0  413    0
    6        1      neutral            3  425    1
    7        1          inc            0  514    0
    8        1          con            1  569    0
```

So the result should look like this:

```
1        1      neutral            3  450    0
2        1          con            1  538    0
3        1      neutral            3  609    0
4        1          inc            0  451    0
5        1          inc            0  413    0
8        1          con            1  569    0
```

I tried this, but apparently that's not right:

```
while (i<=nrow(Pb)){
  if (Pb[i,6]==0 && Pb1[i-1,6]==0) { 
    newfile <- Pb[i,]
  }
  i <- i+1
}
```

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(dt)[, V6 := V6 + shift(V6, 1L, type = "lag")][V6 != 1 | is.na(V6)]`

Comment: Sneaky. Nice one @akrun, I didn't know changing `V6` to a boolean would let you use shift to subset the dt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, by first extracting the rows that you want to remove:

```
rem<-which(Pb[,6]==1)
```

Then you can remove these and the following by doing:

```
Pb<-Pb[-c(rem,rem+1),]
```

If you are concerned that a 1 may be present in the last row, and want to have things unique:

```
rem<-which(Pb[,6]==1)
rem<-c(rem,rem+1)
rem<-rem[rem<nrow(Pb)]
Pb<-Pb[-rem,]
```

Comment: This will break if there's a 1 in the last row

Comment: Actually I'm wrong, it'll just throw a warning. My bad!

Comment: I edited my code anyway, it can be annoying to have warnings in a script :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lag` and `filter` function from `dplyr`:

```
df
#   V1 V2      V3 V4  V5 V6
# 1  1  1 neutral  3 450  0
# 2  2  1     con  1 538  0
# 3  3  1 neutral  3 609  0
# 4  4  1     inc  0 451  0
# 5  5  1     inc  0 413  0
# 6  6  1 neutral  3 425  1
# 7  7  1     inc  0 514  0
# 8  8  1     con  1 569  0

library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(V6 != 1, lag(V6, default = 0) != 1)

#   V1 V2      V3 V4  V5 V6
# 1  1  1 neutral  3 450  0
# 2  2  1     con  1 538  0
# 3  3  1 neutral  3 609  0
# 4  4  1     inc  0 451  0
# 5  5  1     inc  0 413  0
# 6  8  1     con  1 569  0
```

*Data*:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 1:8, V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), V3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("con", 
"inc", "neutral"), class = "factor"), V4 = c(3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 1L), V5 = c(450L, 538L, 609L, 451L, 413L, 425L, 514L, 
569L), V6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!df[, {i1 <- .I[!!V6]; .(c(i1,i1+1))}]$V1]
#   V1 V2      V3 V4  V5 V6
#1:  1  1 neutral  3 450  0
#2:  2  1     con  1 538  0
#3:  3  1 neutral  3 609  0
#4:  4  1     inc  0 451  0
#5:  5  1     inc  0 413  0
#6:  8  1     con  1 569  0
```

Or use `shift`

```
setDT(df)[!V6 & shift(!V6, fill = TRUE)]    
#   V1 V2      V3 V4  V5 V6
#1:  1  1 neutral  3 450  0
#2:  2  1     con  1 538  0
#3:  3  1 neutral  3 609  0
#4:  4  1     inc  0 451  0
#5:  5  1     inc  0 413  0
#6:  8  1     con  1 569  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making up a dataframe:

```
  dfm <- data.frame(a=rnorm(8), b=rbinom(8,1,.2))

#dfm <- structure(list(a = c(-1.06507365382823, 0.64103474967184, 0.0525921813159307, 
0.0465414259158497, -0.65811357438377, -0.466590684535497, -0.246266056446691, 
-0.397561700830275), b = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("a", 
"b"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
  dfm
           a b
1 -1.6687530 0
2 -1.1303493 1
3  0.1415896 0
4  1.8102502 1
5 -1.5421675 0
6  0.1462142 0
7  0.0821345 0
8  0.4063876 0
```

the which() function works nicely for these issues:

```
  rows_with_ones <- which(dfm$b == 1)
  subequent_rows <- rows_with_ones+1
  rows_to_remove <- c(rows_with_ones,subequent_rows)
```

And use the subsetting in base R to remove those rows

```
  dfm2 <- dfm[-rows_to_remove,]
  dfm2
           a b
1 -1.6687530 0
6  0.1462142 0
7  0.0821345 0
8  0.4063876 0
```

Alternatively, you could achieve this quicker and with fewer keystrokes (but maybe not as easy to read for humans) with simple R subsetting:

```
dfm2 <- dfm[dfm$b!=1,]
```

this reads something like, "Subset dfm by the rule where dfm's column "b" does not equal 1, and then assign that object to dfm2"